# Mac dayofweek issue

Tags: macos, date, groovy

Would anyone know why the following code works correctly on Windows and not on Mac??
Today (24/11/2010) should return 47 not 48 as per MacOS

```
def fm_date = '24/11/2010'

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def lPad = {it ->
st = '00' + it.toString()
return st.substring(st.length()-2, st.length())
}

dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
cal=Calendar.getInstance()
cal.setTime( dfm.parse(fm_date) )
now = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,-7)
prev = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,14)
next = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
prev = 'diary' + lPad(prev) + '.shtml'
next = 'diary' + lPad(next) + '.shtml'
return 'diary' + lPad(now) + '.shtml'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's an ISO week number issue...

If I use this code adapted (and groovyfied) from yours:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

def fm_date = '24/11/2010'

Calendar.getInstance().with { cal ->
  // We want ISO Week numbers
  cal.firstDayOfWeek = MONDAY
  cal.minimalDaysInFirstWeek = 4

  setTime new SimpleDateFormat( 'dd/MM/yyyy' ).parse( fm_date )
  now = cal[ WEEK_OF_YEAR ]
}

"diary${"$now".padLeft( 2, '0' )}.shtml"
```

I get `diary47.shtml` returned

As the [documentation for GregorianCalendar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) explains, if you want ISO Month numbers:

> Values calculated for the WEEK_OF_YEAR
>   field range from 1 to 53. Week 1 for a
>   year is the earliest seven day period
>   starting on getFirstDayOfWeek() that
>   contains at least
>   getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days from
>   that year. It thus depends on the
>   values of getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(),
>   getFirstDayOfWeek(), and the day of
>   the week of January 1. Weeks between
>   week 1 of one year and week 1 of the
>   following year are numbered
>   sequentially from 2 to 52 or 53 (as
>   needed).
>
> For example, January 1, 1998 was a
>   Thursday. **If getFirstDayOfWeek() is
>   MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()
>   is 4 (these are the values reflecting
>   ISO 8601 and many national standards),
>   then week 1 of 1998 starts on December
>   29, 1997, and ends on January 4, 1998**.
>   If, however, getFirstDayOfWeek() is
>   SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on
>   January 4, 1998, and ends on January
>   10, 1998; the first three days of 1998
>   then are part of week 53 of 1997.

---

**Edit**

Even Groovier (from John's comment)

```
def fm_date = '24/11/2010'

Calendar.getInstance().with { cal ->
  // We want ISO Week numbers
  cal.firstDayOfWeek = MONDAY
  cal.minimalDaysInFirstWeek = 4

  cal.time = Date.parse( 'dd/MM/yyyy', fm_date )
  now = cal[ WEEK_OF_YEAR ]
}

"diary${"$now".padLeft( 2, '0' )}.shtml"
```

**Edit2**

Just ran this on Windows using VirtualBox, and got the same result

Comment: Thats fabulous... Little bit more grooviness below taking out the simple date format.. Still not sure why the     cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) calculates differently on mac and PC which is where the issue seems to be....

Comment: <code>    def fm_date = '24/11/2010'

    Calendar.getInstance().with { cal ->
      // We want ISO Week numbers
      cal.firstDayOfWeek = MONDAY
      cal.minimalDaysInFirstWeek = 4
      cal.setTime(Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', fm_date ))
      now = cal[ WEEK_OF_YEAR ]
    }

"diary${"$now".padLeft( 2, '0' )}.shtml"</code>

Comment: Does that code work differently on a Mac and Windows?  I suspect it might be different initial values for firstDayOfWeek and minimalDaysInFirstWeek on the two platforms...  I get `diary47.shtml` on a Mac (but can't test Windows) :-/

Comment: <pre><code> 
    def fm_date = '24/11/2010' 
     Calendar.getInstance().with { cal -> 
     // We want ISO Week numbers 
     cal.firstDayOfWeek = MONDAY 
      cal.minimalDaysInFirstWeek = 4 
     cal.setTime(Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', fm_date )) 
     now = cal[ WEEK_OF_YEAR ] 
     } 
     "diary${"$now".padLeft( 2, '0' )}.shtml"
        
     </code></pre>

Comment: No worries...added it to the bottom of my answer instead ;-)  Including replacing the `setTime` call with a more groovy setter call.  Fingers crossed this code gives the same result on Windows to Mac (as I said, it gives the expected result on Mac)

Comment: Tim, thanks.. yes the issue was thrown up because I use Groovy inside Filemaker, developed the code, but the end user is on PC so instantly it changed all the webpage names... I am using javascript inside the web page to go to the right 'page' based on the current date and it would definitely appear as if the Mac changes the year start date.. Might be apple jvm??? ANyway it works the saem oon both now so thank you very much.